# Why inner class can not access outer class method which is overload between normal method and static method?

Tags: java, overloading

I have a test class like this.
The inner class has a method `c()`.
`c()` has three line code.
The first line and third line is fine, but the second line is error which say `a(java.lang.String) has private access`.
Why the method `b()` is fine but the method `a(String s)` which is overload is error?

```
public class Test {

    public void a() {
    }

    private static void a(String s) {
    }

    private static void b() {
    }

    private class Inner extends Test{
        void c() {
            a();
            a("");
            b();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have try with jdk1.8,but there is not error

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code other than the faulty line. You have to access the method in a static way, like so: `Test.a("");`.

Comment: The static a(...) is not an overload. It's a bad idea. To overload it should have been ``public void a(String s) {...}``.

Comment: `a(java.lang.String) has private access` while true is irrelevant to the question and not an issue / problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step of overload resolution is determining in which class to search for the applicable methods ([JLS §15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1)):

> #### 15.12.1. Compile-Time Step 1: Determine Class or Interface to Search

If you follow this section through, you will see that in this case,

> If the form is MethodName, that is, just an Identifier, then:
>
> If the Identifier appears in the scope of a method declaration with that name (§6.3, §6.4.1), then
>
> If there is an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member, let T be the innermost such type declaration. The class or interface to search is T.

For `a()` and `a("")`, `T` is `Inner`. For `b()`, `T` is `Test`. `Inner` is the inner most type declaration that contains a method with the name `a`. This is because `Inner` inherits the parameterless `a` from `Test` (but not the `a` that accepts a string, since that is private).

For `a()`, the inherited, parameterless `a` in `Inner` is successfully found in later steps of overload resolution. For `a("")`, however, there is no `a` that accepts a `String` in `Inner`! The compiler is smart enough to look for private methods in the super class and output a "not accessible" message.

To call the `a`s declared in `Test`, you should qualify it:

```
Test.this.a(); // or super.a(), note the different objects on which the method is called
Test.a("");
```

As an experiment, you can try making `Inner` not inherit `Test` and see what happens. Now there is no method declaration with the name `a` in `Inner`, the "innermost such type declaration" would be `Test`, and all 3 of the simple name calls would work.